# NoneType has no attribute 'rfind' when compiling Less with django-pipeline

Tags: django, less, nonetype

I'm trying to compile some `.less` files using `django-pipeline`. When I run `collectstatic`, everything copies over correctly, and then I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 35, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 459, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 163, in handle_noargs
    collected = self.collect()
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 119, in collect
    dry_run=self.dry_run)
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/storage.py", line 26, in post_process
    output_file = packager.pack_stylesheets(package)
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/packager.py", line 90, in pack_stylesheets
    variant=package.variant, **kwargs)
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/packager.py", line 99, in pack
    paths = self.compile(package.paths)
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/packager.py", line 93, in compile
    return self.compiler.compile(paths)
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/compilers/__init__.py", line 34, in compile
    compiled_content = compiler.compile_file(content, finders.find(path))
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/compilers/less.py", line 19, in compile_file
    cwd = os.path.dirname(path)
  File ".../lib64/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 120, in dirname
    i = p.rfind('/') + 1
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

I don't think I've done anything weird with the types in my `settings.py`, but here's the relevant bit of it just in case:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage"

PIPELINE = True

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ("projectname", os.path.join(REPO_ROOT, "static")),
)

PIPELINE_COMPILERS = (
    'pipeline.compilers.coffee.CoffeeScriptCompiler',
    'pipeline.compilers.less.LessCompiler'
)

PIPELINE_JS = {
    'projectname': {
        'source_filenames': ('js/*.coffee',),
        'output_filename': 'projectname/js.js'
    }
}

PIPELINE_CSS = {
    'projectname': {
        'source_filenames': ('css/style.less',),
        'output_filename': 'projectname/css.css'
    }
}
```

If I replace my CSS `source_filenames` with a glob (ie `css/*.less`) I get the same result. The file is definitely where I'm telling it it is (at the very least, if I replace it with a path that I know is wrong, I get a different error). With the `PIPELINE_CSS` lines commented out, my CoffeeScript compiles to JS just fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try running this :

`$ python manage.py findstatic css/style.less`

If you have this result :

`No matching file found for 'css/style.less'.`

You're likely misconfigured `staticfiles`, otherwise let me know too.

Comment: Turns out that because I had given my site static files the namespace `projectname` in `STATICFILES_DIRS`, I needed to set `source_filenames` to `('projectname/css/style.less',)`. Weird, because the JS is in the same place, but it only works **without** `projectname` in the path. Go figure.

Comment: I had the same error, but in my case it was not specifying an output_filename. Hopefully that helps someone coming across this question.